# How to setup Pycharm and JDK on ubuntu

Tags: java, python, ubuntu

I am going to develop some functionality using python and I need to setup pycharm but it depends on some dependencies like open JDK of oracle.
How can setup these two.

Comment: This question would probably receive better answers if asked on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: If you're installing pycharm with apt-get, doesn't it ask to install dependencies?

Comment: yap sorry was using stackoverflow and forgot that sorry

Answer (score 3):

When you have downloaded a package from Oracle site, unpack it and copy its contents into for example `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_51/`.

Then, type following commands:

`sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/java" 1`

`sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/javac" 1`

`sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/javaws" 1`

and in the end:

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`

and choose the the number of your Oracle Java installation.

Comment: This indeed provided insight to me. For now I can grasp this `update-aternatives` far better than before. Also solved my PyCharm 2016 trouble

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have Oracle JRE 1.6+ or OpenJDK 1.7+.
To make sure of that, please check $java -version in your system terminal.

If you already have an appropriate JRE, then you’re just a couple of minutes away from finishing installation.

If not, please follow the instructions in order to install OpenJDK:

[http://openjdk.java.net/install/](https://openjdk.java.net/install/)

or Oracle JRE:

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/linux/linux-jre.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/linux/linux-jre.html)

The downloaded PyCharm archive name looks like:

pycharm-educational-*.tar.gz

Follow these steps:

```
1. Copy the pycharm-educational-*.tar.gz to the desired installation location, preferably new empty directory. Make sure you have read-write permissions for that directory.
2. Unpack pycharm-educational-*.tar.gz using the following command:
3. tar xfz pycharm-educational-*.tar.gz
4. Remove pycharm-educational-*.tar.gz to save disk space (optional)
5. Run pycharm.sh from the bin subdirectory
```

That’s it!

Comment: But why do I need JRE I thought JDK  is enough for Pycharm

Comment: Choose one. JDK or JRE.